# How can I make docker-compose bind the containers only on defined network instead of 0.0.0.0?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In recent versions `docker-compose` automatically creates a new network for the services it creates. Basically, every `docker-compose` setup is getting its own IP range, so that in theory I could call my services on the network's IP address with the predefined ports. This is great when developing multiple projects at the same time, since there is then no need to change the ports in `docker-compose.yml` (i.e. I can run multiple `nginx` projects at the same time on port 8080 on different interfaces)

However, this does not work as intended: every exposed port is still exposed on 0.0.0.0 and thus there are port conflicts with multiple projects. It is possible to put the bind IP into `docker-compose.yml`, however this is a killer for portability -- not every developer on the team uses the same OS or works on the same projects, therefore it's not clear which IP to configure.

It's be great to define the IP to bind the containers to in terms of the network created for this particular project. `docker-compose` should both know which network it created as well as its IP, so this shouldn't be a problem, however I couldn't find an easy way to do it. Is there a way or is this something yet to be implemented?

EDIT: An example of a port conflict: imagine two projects, each with an application server running on port 8080 and a MySQL database running on port 3306, both respectively exposed as "8080:8080" and "3306:3306". Running the first one with `docker-compose` creates a network called something like `app1_network` with an IP range of 172.18.0.0/16. Every exposed port is exposed on 0.0.0.0, i.e. on 127.0.0.1, on the WAN address, on the default bridge (172.17.0.0/16) and also on the 172.18.0.0/16. In this case I can reach my application server of all of 127.0.0.1:8080, 172.17.0.1:8080, 172.18.0.1:8080 and als on `$WAN_IP:8080`. If I start the second application now, it starts a second network `app2_network` 172.19.0.0/16, but still tries to bind every exposed port on all interfaces. Those ports are of course already taken (except for 172.19.0.1). If there had been a possibility to restrict each application to its network, application 1 would have available at 172.18.0.1:8080 and the second at 172.19.0.1:8080 and I wouldn't need to change port mappings to 8081 and 3307 respectively to run both applications at the same time.

Comment: Why are there port conflicts? Can you provide further details?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I've extended the question, I hope it helps rather than confuses.

Comment: Lots of possible solutions. Do you need to publish the port? Are you connecting to app of these from something running outside of docker containers? Are all the ports you need to publish serving http? Do they all need to be on the same port outside of docker?

Comment: @BMitch we are talking about a development environment, so there is only the need to expose all the ports for the developer on the local machine -- ideally without rotating port numbers for multiple projects, but instead access different projects on different networks. Might get a lot more difficult with things like Docker for Mac, but that's a different problem to tackle.

Comment: Are you asking if you can have multiple applications listen on the same IP and port number? The docker networks should be considered internal to docker, for container-to-container communication.

Comment: @BMitch same port number, but not the same IP. Currently, they listen on all available IPs. I just want the IP to be automatically determined based on application's network and not on manual entry in the `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 114):

In your service configuration, in docker-compose.yml:

```
ports:
 - "127.0.0.1:8001:8001"
```

Reference: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#ports

Comment: Even though it's been some time: that's not really the answer I'm looking for. For each stack, `docker-compose` makes a new network, e.g. `172.18.0.1/16`. Since this network is already exclusive to my stack and it's available on my machine, I would like the containers inside this network to bind against that device and not against every network device on my machine. Binding to localhost does not solve port conflicts and manually setting the ports kind of defeats the point of having a separate network.

Comment: I got `services.nginx.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object`

Comment: @EmmanuelMericdeBellefon  this happens due to edgy yaml parsing. The quotes are mandatory, without them parsing `127.0.0.1:8001:8001` evaluates as `<attribute>:hash` with broken shape.

Comment: good rule: if a yaml value starts with templates escape or contains : then quote it. there are other cases, like numbers which might be evaluated as integer with special base too, leading to other strange phenomenon, but it is the same fix. Neuter your values :)

Answer (score 16):

You can publish a port to a single IP address on the host by including the IP before the ports:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 -d nginx
```

The above runs nginx on the loopback interface. You can use a similar port mapping inside of a docker-compose.yml file. e.g.:

```
ports:
  - "127.0.0.1:80:80"
```

`docker-compose` doesn't have any special abilities to infer which network interface to use based on the docker network. You'd need to specify the unique IP address to use in each compose file, and that IP needs to be for a network interface on your host. For a developer machine, that IP may change as DHCP gives the laptop/workstation new addresses.

Because of the difficulty implementing your goal, most would either map different ports on the host to different containers, so 13307:3307 for container a, 23307:3307 for container b, 33307:3307 for container c, or whatever number scheme makes sense for you. And when dealing with HTTP traffic, then using a reverse proxy like traefik often makes the most sense.

Answer (score 16):

It can be achieved by configuring network in docker-compose file.

Please consider below two docker-compose files. There is still drawback of needing to specify subnet unique across all project you work on at the same time. On the other hand you need to know which service you connecting too - this is why it cannot assign it dynamically.

my-project.yaml:

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    networks:
      - my-project-network
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80

networks:
  my-project-network:
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4: "172.20.0.1"
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "172.20.0.0/16"
```

my-other-project.yaml

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    networks:
      - my-other-project-network
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80

networks:
  my-other-project-network:
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4: "172.21.0.1"
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "172.21.0.0/16"
```

Note: that if you have other service binding to *:80 like for instance apache running on host - it will also bind on docker-compose networks' interfaces and you will not be able to use this port.

To run above two services:

```sh
docker-compose -f my-project.yaml up -d
docker-compose -f my-other-project.yaml up -d
```

Comment: Ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#driver_opts