# Add Network options to docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm currently using a *docker compose* to run a stack.

The compose creates a custom network with

```
networks:
  LabNetwork:
    external: true
```

I have to set the network setting `com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4` but I have no idea on how to add it and I can't find anything on the documentation

Comment: Does this answer your question (search for `driver_opts` in the answers)? [How can I make docker-compose bind the containers only on defined network instead of 0.0.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109398/how-can-i-make-docker-compose-bind-the-containers-only-on-defined-network-instea)